# Flutter app failed to build or run on android

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

My flutter app runs well on an i.o.s simulator but does not run when I use an android emulator, also, when I try to create an android build, it runs into the same errors. When I ran `flutter build apk`, it initializes with no errors, resolves dependencies with no errors, but fails to run the task `Gradle task 'assembleRelease'` and ends with `Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0`. Below is a more detailed view of the error logs.

```
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                          6.6s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried changing the compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28 in `android/app/build.gradle` but it still throws the same error. What can I do?

Comment: Is there any log from the gradle invocation? There should be a more detailed error from AAPT2 explaining why it failed

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska, I do not know where to find gradle invocation. Can you kindly help inform me on where to find it or send me a link to a resource that I can use to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with flutter but I think running with "-v" should give you more output.